# Sort all elements of a single associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Assume an associative array with a single element

```
 array('red'=> 3, 'blue'=> 6, 'yellow'=> 2, 'orange'=> 1)
```

I need to sort those keys ascending (or descending), and place each sorted element into wa new array, to end up with separate array elements, as in

```
myarray[] = array('orange' => 1);
myarray[] = array('yellow' => 2);
myarray[] = array('red'    => 3);
myarray[] = array('blue'   => 6);
```

**Added**

My first thought was to use asort/ksort, but those functions seem to require multiple array elements. In my case, there is just one array element. I need to sort the *contents* of a single associative array element.

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asort()` and `arsort()` will allow you to sort the array based on values. If you're looking to have a 2-D array, you can do the following:

```
$arr = array('red' => 3,
             'blue' => 6,
             'yellow' => 2, 
             'orange' => 1);
$my_sorted_arr = [];
asort($arr); // Use arsort($arr) for reverse (descending) order
foreach($arr AS $k => $v) {
   $my_sorted_arr[] = array($k => $v);
}

print_r($my_sorted_arr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orange] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [yellow] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [red] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [blue] => 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any loop, just you can use uasort() and array_chunk() for this, so here your solution:

```php
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('red'=> 3, 'blue'=> 6, 'yellow'=> 2, 'orange'=> 1);

// Sort $array
uasort($array, 'cmp');

// chunk your array and save it
$final = array_chunk($array, 1, TRUE);

// print your results
echo print_r($final);
```